# why there's a different behavior in template initialization between g++ and clang++?

Tags: c++, templates

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

template <typename T> std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const std::vector<T> &vec)
{
    if (vec.empty()) {
        out << "[]";
        return out;
    }
    out << '[';
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size() - 1; i++) {
        out << vec[i] << ", ";
    }
    return out << vec.back() << ']';
}
template <class T, std::size_t C> std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const std::array<T, C> &arr)
{
    if (arr.empty()) {
        out << "<>";
        return out;
    }
    out << '<';
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size() - 1; i++) {
        out << arr[i] << ", ";
    }
    return out << arr.back() << '>';
}

#include <string>
#define dbg(...) logger(__LINE__, #__VA_ARGS__, __VA_ARGS__)
template <typename... Args> void logger(int line, std::string vars, Args &&...values)
{
    std::cerr << "Ln " << line << ": " << vars << " = ";
    std::string delim = "";
    (..., (std::cerr << delim << values, delim = ", "));
    std::cerr << std::endl, std::cerr.flush();
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    using a2i = array<int, 2>;
    using va2i = vector<a2i>;
    using a4v = array<va2i, 4>;
    
    a4v a4;
    a4[0].push_back({3, 5});
    a4[1].push_back({9, 8}), a4[1].push_back({1, 2});
    
    dbg(a4);

    return 0;
}
```

compiling above code on `https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_clang` and `https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_gcc` you'll get different result.

g++ one will compile and work as expected while clang++ complains like:

```
96501129/source.cpp:36:6: warning: pack fold expression is a C++17 extension [-Wc++17-extensions]
    (..., (std::cerr << delim << values, delim = ", "));
     ^
96501129/source.cpp:13:13: error: call to function 'operator<<' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
        out << vec[i] << ", ";
            ^
96501129/source.cpp:25:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'operator<<<std::__1::array<int, 2> >' requested here
        out << arr[i] << ", ";
            ^
96501129/source.cpp:36:31: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'operator<<<std::__1::vector<std::__1::array<int, 2>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::array<int, 2> > >, 4>' requested here
    (..., (std::cerr << delim << values, delim = ", "));
                              ^
96501129/source.cpp:52:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'logger<std::__1::array<std::__1::vector<std::__1::array<int, 2>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::array<int, 2> > >, 4> &>' requested here
    dbg(a4);
    ^
96501129/source.cpp:31:18: note: expanded from macro 'dbg'
#define dbg(...) logger(__LINE__, #__VA_ARGS__, __VA_ARGS__)
                 ^
96501129/source.cpp:17:49: note: 'operator<<' should be declared prior to the call site
template <class T, std::size_t C> std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const std::array<T, C> &arr)
                                                ^
96501129/source.cpp:15:16: error: call to function 'operator<<' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
    return out << vec.back() << ']';
               ^
96501129/source.cpp:17:49: note: 'operator<<' should be declared prior to the call site
template <class T, std::size_t C> std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const std::array<T, C> &arr)
                                                ^
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
```

it seems like that the clang can't initialize the template of `<<` operator on `ostream` object with type the `array<int, 2>` as `array` instance in the inner most layer.

the out most array of size 4 and the vector of array gets rendered successfully while the inner most one doesn't on this type of `array<vector<array<int, 2>>, 4>`.

I wonder what's the reason for this complain and how to fix the code to make it work on both gcc and clang

Comment: You're testing on an outdated GCC. GCC 12 and newer rejects your code too. Your error message from Clang seems to be cut short, I get a more detailed error [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4xn4q1zYT), which explains the issue. Ultimately, operators must be overloaded where ADL can find them (i.e. normally in the same namespace as one of the operands), meaning you can't sanely overload operators for standard classes, since you're not allowed to add your operators to `namespace std`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You can overload `<<` for standard containers just fine, you just need to jump through some (not very challenging) [hoops](https://godbolt.org/z/e7qKsWrcf)

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Eh. I guess this works, but it forces you to bake those overloads into the logger. You can't add more ADL-less overloads from the client code. I'd go with something like a specializable trait `template <typename T> struct PrintToStream{...};` over this.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI why is that we need first declaring the template functions then implementing them instead of writing those functions in new namespace directly?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat could you please illustrate how you archive it by a helper struct `PrintToStream`?

Comment: @LiuWeibo They can reference each other, for example when you have an array of vectors or a vector of arrays. So both implementations should see each other's declaration.

Comment: Something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/cdzYErc7q Rushed it, but it seems to work.